Correctly escaping <CR>: how can I map a command to send the literal string "<CR>" to a vim function?
I'm currently trying to create a mapping that sends a command and a newline to an open terminal using nnoremap and term_sendkeys().
term_sendkeys() interprets the \<CR> string as a newline, so it would make sense to make a command similar to this one.
:nnoremap <F4> :call term_sendkeys(term_list()[0], "python models.py -m something\<CR>")<CR>

However, the first <CR> is translated as a newline by :nnoremap. This make the mapping fail, since there's a newline in the middle of a literal string inside a :call.
What's the correct way to escape <CR> inside a Vim mapping?

Try: \<lt>cr>

Thanks @Heptite!

You should extract the whole RHS of your mapping into a function that you call from the mapping:
function! MyFunc()
    call term_sendkeys(term_list()[0], "python models.py -m something\<CR>")
endfunction
nnoremap <F4> <Cmd>call MyFunc()<CR>


@Heptite found a solution in the comments: I can escape < to <lt>.
:nnoremap <F4> :call term_sendkeys(term_list()[0], "python models.py -m something\<lt>CR>")<CR>


<CR> is nothing but byte #13, so it can be written as \r or \x0d like in a normal C string.
Likewise, <NL> is the same as \n. Other keys can be passed unescaped, so they will get preprocessed by map only.
Of course, there is also \<lt>cr> but such stuff should better stay in reserve for even more complex scenario.

That doesn't work, since byte#13 teminates the opened quote " which makes :call fail parsing.

I think that a <CR> inside a pair of "" inside a term_sendkeys inside a :call inside a nnoremap in a Vim command is a complex enough scenario :-)
